# How to hide button after click

Tags: ios, swift

I create `Start_button` and make `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction`

```
@IBOutlet weak var Start_button: UIButton!

@IBAction func Start_button(sender: AnyObject)
```

Now, i want hide button after click. I try this, but this don't work:

```
@IBAction func Start_button(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        Start_button.hidden = true;
    }
```

Error message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

How i can hide this button?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: delete the outlet , and connect it again with the diff name. Also rename your action method to a diff name.

Comment: @Alexander change the sender parameter to UIButton and just change the sender.hidden to true  `@IBAction  func startButtonAction(sender: UIButton) { sender.hidden = true }`

Comment: If you would like to toggle it  `sender.hidden = !sender.hidden`

Comment: Don't forget to right click your button and delete the old connections

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29873351/2303865

Comment: I try "change the sender parameter to UIButton and just change the sender.hidden to true @IBAction func startButtonAction(sender: UIButton) { sender.hidden = true }"
And i delete the old connections.
Xcode don't show error, but button no hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its nil because you probably haven't connected it from your storyboard/nib. You need to connect the outlet, you can't just create an outlet in code and expect it to be connected to the visible element. The same goes for your action. `@IBOutlet` / `@IBAction` stands for `Interface Builder Outlet/Action`, which means you have to connect them in `Interface Builder`.

Also its better if your action uses the sender, and not a local variable (when its pointing to the same thing). And you shouldnt use `;`at the end of the line.

```
@IBAction func Start_button(sender: UIButton) // Change to UIButton
{
    sender.hidden = true
    // OR
    // (sender as! UIButton).hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I create `@IBOutlet / @IBAction` for button with press CTRL and drag to the code. 

When i try use `sender.hidden = true`
Xcode show me error: `Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'hidden'`

Comment: Change AnyObject to UIButton

Comment: IBActions and IBOutlets should follow the same naming convention as vars and methods in Swift

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func button_nameA(sender: AnyObject) {
// show hidden buttons
    self.Target_Object.hidden = false

}
```

So when you click the A buttons its automaticly send to you target and in target also you have to hide button if you working single view app